# Bootstrap responsive scaling issue on smaller than 1920 x 1080 resolutions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a private video site that's main aimed towards my home networks and the desktop computers, however, the site was constructed on a 1920x1080 resolution so if that's any smaller that site looks like a catastrophe. here is the code for the page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-trans navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div style="width:66%" class="container">
        <div  class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="index.php">Network TV</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="width:100%; height=:100%; color:black; margin-top:13%; text-align:center; border: 0">
  <div class="row center-row">
    <div style="width:10%" class="col-md-4"><div style="background-color:transparetn" class="well"><p><u><h4>Season1</h4></u></p></div></div>
      <div style="width:10%"class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p><u><h4>Season2<h4></u></p></div></div>
      <div style="width:10%"class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p><u><h4>Season3</u></p></div></div>
      <div style="width:10%"class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p><u><h4>Season4</h4></u></p></div></div>
      <div style="width:10%"class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p><u><h4>Season5</h4></u></p></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I want to know**

My question is why does this not scale down properly, when the screen is smaller I want the margins to adjust to fix the screen, but instead it all just goes into a vertical list all mixed my and improperly scaled

Comment: So whats ur Question?!

Comment: Sorry for this extremely late reply, my question is why does this not scale down properly, when the screen is smaller I want the margins to adjust to fix the screen, but instead it all just goes into a vertical list all mixed my and improperly scaled

Comment: You did not provide any CSS code. as by you naming convention `scaling down` is a matter of CSS, u must add some clear, concise simplified css according to the html parts in ur question

Comment: Im using bootstrap css its way to big to attach

Comment: I didnt say u just put ur whole website here and let others code it for u. I just said add the related section of ur CSS to the markup enclosed to ur question. please read carefully:)

Comment: The css i'm using is in line styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap you have no need for all the extra inline styles, by setting inline widths to your html you are taking away what makes bootstrap "boostrap" for sizing, bootstrap has a grid system, if you follow the grid system, your site will work correctly. Please read: w3 fools has a great starting point for begginers.  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Also, after looking at your code I noticed you have col-4 set to 10% width, it does not work like that. col-4, is more like 33% if you are using the most common 12 column grid. that means by setting col-4 to 10% you are over riding bootstrap key features and is why it is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, ill research it now!

Comment: Thanks I got it working, however ill have to rewrite the whole table, but at least it will work this time :D thanks really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your example the last `div` should be `</nav>` for one thing. Along with this style tag inside of the `container` > `style="width:66%"`. I would start with those things first.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="index.php">Network TV</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--CHANGE TO NAV-->
```